# SAML 2.0 protocol support in .Net 4.5 standard

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.5, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I’m looking for a package to support SAML protocol on my IDP built in .Net 4.5 standard. I need to return SAML responses to the SP, either SP initiated or IDP initiated.

Do you have a solution for this without upgrading to .Net core with Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) support ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use componentSpace saml library.
We are using both. Net 4.5 and . Net core libraries and it is a great solution.
https://www.componentspace.com/saml-for-asp-net?gclid=CjwKCAjw_o-HBhAsEiwANqYhp7BkOttS4Vve4QHJz-PS6taO89AV6gflhB6FgUZMmuZ1qNq65wgsDhoCf4wQAvD_BwE

If you are not willing to purchase any tool, you can write code by yourself as well. If you follow the saml standards carefully, it will be easy to code.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you not to write the code yourself!

There is a list of SAML [client-side stacks](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) here.

I'm confused about the reference to WIF though because WIF is WS-Federation not SAML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 package do not support neither .NET Framework 4.5 or WIF.

You need to upgrade to at least .NET Framework 4.6.1.